# get unchecked checkboxes using just javascript

Tags: javascript

I can get all checked checkboxes with:

`document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')`

Is there a way to get the unchecked boxes?

Comment: I dont know who upvoted this question where no effort has been made

Comment: someone that understands document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked') does show effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `not` psuedo-selector in combination with `checked`:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length
);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and trying to work out how to use it in my code - looking for multiple cases of checked/not checked/Jquery/not Jquery. Im not a javascript ninja - so in the end, it was a little more convoluted, but I wrote my own little routine. I pulled back *everything* using:

```
`var formData = $(':input');`
```

this pulled back ALL inputs checked/not checked/text/select - everything. The result was an array of objects stored in the var "formData".

With an array it has useful things like length/values etc that I could iterate through and look for the result.

```
 `for( var i = 0; i < formData.length; i++){
        if(formData[i].type === "checkbox"){
            inputName = formData[i].name.toUpperCase();
            inputValue = formData[i].checked === true ? "1" : "0" ;
 `
```

You could even step over all other inputs like buttons etc with a line like:

```
`if( (inputs[i].nodeName === "INPUT" || inputs[i].nodeName === "SELECT") && inputs[i].type != "hidden" ){ `
```

Like I said - convoluted - but it works for me - and in a library I only needed to write it once..... I'm sure the purists out there will pull me up on it - but as I said - "it works for me"

If you need any more explanation, let me know.

Hope this helps.